# Selenium: embed chromeDriver into one exe

Tags: c#, selenium, embed, selenium-chromedriver

I have a program running selenium, and uses the chromedriver. 
However, I want my program to be 1 solid exe file. 
How can I embed the chrome driver into the exe so I do not have to have the main program, and chromedriver in a folder together in order to work.

Is this possible? C# visual studios

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of C#, but following are some general guidelines to achieve the task:

1. Add chromedriver.exe into the project folder (like /lib folder)
2. Calculate absolute path from the relative path (project root folder/lib). relative path to the project root folder.
3. Set absolute path in "webdriver.chrome.driver".
4. While exporting include the .exe file.
5. Try it out on new machine.